# Strange coordinate units

Tags: r, gis

I received a .gdb file that I need to do analysis on. This is an ESRI file, but I don't have access to any ESRI products. I opened it in R using the "rgdal" package, but the coordinates it displays seem very off.

For example, (-9288065, 4604652) should map to Kentucky. My initial thought was that there are missing decimals, so it should be -92.88 and -46.04, but this maps to somewhere north of Kentucky, which is wrong.

Do these coordinate units look familiar? How might I convert them to latitude and longitude?

Comment: You are probably going to get a better answer at the Stack Exchange site dedicated to GIS questions: [gis.se].

Comment: Those coordinates at not in lat/long but likely some kind of NAD83 state plane, I'm guessing Kentucky. You need to know what type of projection they are, and whether they're in feet or meters. Just trying a few, I can't get any close, so it's possible they're not any state plane. Ask whoever sent it to you what projection it is in.

Comment: Take a look at calling `sp::proj4string` on your spatial object. This will tell you the projection. I don't think it's missing decimals; rather, it looks like it might be a projection with units of feet, which might show up in the proj4 string. You can also get info on projections by CRS code at http://spatialreference.org/

Comment: @camille The result was the following: "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs", which I don't know how to interpret (I don't have a GIS background).

Comment: "+proj=merc" means it's a mercator projection, and "+units=m" means it's in meters. Take a look at the tutorial on changing projections [here](http://rspatial.org/spatial/rst/6-crs.html). Do you know what projection you want?

Comment: @camille I'd just like to obtain the latitude and longitude coordinates, which I obtained using transform function in the link provided. Much appreciated!

Comment: [Here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=kentucky) is a list of spatial references for Kentucky that your data might be using. I tried a few but didn't get close either.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with help from @camille.

For future users:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

myFeatureClass<-readOGR('your_data_here')

#checks the projection type
sp::proj4string(myFeatureClass)

#convert projection to longlat 
final_data <- as.data.frame(spTransform(myFeatureClass, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
```